# SWE vs. AI…career change

Tags: training, philosophy

I’m looking to switch careers and really want to take the dive, but became hesitant after chatgpt. My question is will it be worth it to devote time, energy and money into the switch if it’s likely to become “obsolete”?

Didn’t know where to go that I would get straight answers. Thanks in advance

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's off-topic. We don't provide career path recommendation. That's explicitly written in our on-topic/off-topic pages.

Comment: Didn’t mean to post off topic. I was directed to this site by a friend because I could most likely find the help I’m looking for here. If this is not the forum and you know the place I could find what I’m looking for could you let me know?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know of a website where you could ask this. However, you could try to ask your question in our chat room: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43371/the-singularity.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to create a "right" answer for this question, but I will share my thoughts.

Software Engineering has been, is and for many years will be a great field to work in. Many companies (small and large ones) are FAR behind the current status of technology, there will still be companies looking for HTML and CSS Engineers in 10-20 years. While the latest advances in AI are astonishing, they will take years, if not decades, to fully emerge into the workspace of most companies.

However, the rise of AI could very well be one of the greatest achievements humankind has ever made. Hopping in the trend of prompting ChatGPT for giggles is one thing - understanding, developing and improving AI is another. In my opinion AI will not fully replace Software Engineers for quite some time, currently it seems as though the partner-programming idea is the most successful.

AI has the potential to change our species forever, I find nothing more intriguing than being part of this development. If you have the time and resources to target an AI career path, do it. But it is definitely not a must-do, as "normal" software engineers are heavily in demand and will continue to be. If anything, AI is more of a shoot for the moon - it could very well be that we have to admit AGI is not possible for the sake of hardware constraints.

I'd also say that you don't have to see it as black&white: being an AI expert does not mean you cannot work in "normal" Software Engineering. I see it as a nice add-on, as it certainly will capture more and more parts of the software development process.

Comment: This was very helpful and on par with what I was hoping to find! Would you happen to know of another place I could dive a little deeper into this topic?